# How to import a template tag in the interactive shell?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-shell

How can I import a custom template tag or filter in the interactive shell to see if the everything is working fine?

I have two machines behaving differently and I don't have a clue of how to do some debugging.

On the production machine I can't load a template filter, I get the error "Template library not found".
On the local machine everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about typos, missing `__init__.py` problems or masked `ImportError`s, you could just import the function. Assuming the following structure:

```
foo
├── bar
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── ..
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── ..
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── baz.py
│   ├── views.py
├── manage.py
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

and the following contents of `baz.py`:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def capitalize(value):
    return value.capitalize()
```

you would just run

```
>>> from bar.templatetags import baz
>>> print baz.capitalize('test')
'test'
```

Comment: i chose yours as accepted answer because is very detailed. Thanks to everybody for your very fast answers.

Answer (score 6):

Importing filters like this:

```
from django.template import defaultfilters as filters
filters.date( date.today() )
```

Instead default filters you should import your custom filter:

```
from myApp.templatetags import poll_extras
poll_extras.cut( 'ello' )
```

Double check settings installed app in your production server.